# Flutter Rive, Flare Actor syncing is not perfect

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flare, rive

I have two of below

```
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("print anything");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: circleMainBtnSize,
                    width: circleMainBtnSize,
                    child: FlareActor(
                      "assets/rive/somefile.flr",
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      animation: "someani",
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

and the animation is roatating shape.

but the problem is the two of FlareActor are starting rotating at different time I guess (sometime it is and sometime is not (mostly when emulator first opened))

how do I fix this?